# Gaussian Shader for OpenGL ES not working on Mali GPU but working properly on Adreno and PowerVR

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I created a Gaussian Blur filter on OpenGL ES. I have found out that it is not working on Mali GPUs. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong. I have already tried to break long calculation into small steps but to no avail. Then I pass 1/resoution as resolution instead of calculating it during loops to avoid division operations. It started showing a slightly dimmer image, however, it still did not blurred the image.

EDIT:
I have already tried converting lowp to mediump but it not help.
Not working means that I am getting a slightly dimmer version of the original image.
The GPU is Mali-G52 MC2.
Lastly, I generated the entire shader without loops and pre-computed gaussian values. But to no avail.

This is working as intended on other GPU platforms.

```
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
uniform lowp vec2 resolution;
void main()
{
    lowp vec2 uv = vec2(textureCoordinate.x, textureCoordinate.y);
    lowp vec3 sum = vec3(0.0);
    lowp float intensity = 15.0;
    lowp float width_hal = float(int(intensity/2.0));
    lowp vec3 color = vec3(0.0);
    lowp float red = 0.0;
    lowp float green = 0.0;
    lowp float blue = 0.0;

for (lowp float i = 0.0; i < intensity; i=i+1.0){
    for (lowp float j = 0.0; j < intensity; j = j+1.0){
        lowp float guas_value = 1.0 / (2.0 * 3.14159 * (4.0 * 4.0)) * pow(2.718, -((i-intensity / 2.0)*(i-intensity / 2.0)+(j-intensity / 2.0)*(j-intensity / 2.0))/(2.0 * (4.0 * 4.0)));
        lowp float x_axis = uv.x + ((-width_hal + i) * resolution.x * 1.5);
        lowp float y_axis = uv.y + ((-width_hal + j) * resolution.y * 1.5);
        color = texture2D(
                        inputImageTexture, vec2(
                        x_axis,
                        y_axis
                    )
                ).rgb;
        red += color.r * guas_value;
        green += color.g * guas_value;
        blue += color.b * guas_value;
    }
}

gl_FragColor = vec4(red, green, blue, 1.0);
};
```

Comment: If you change all your lowp to mediump, does it improve things? Lowp range can be as small as -2 to 2 depending on the GPU.

Comment: Which Mali GPUs? What does "not working" mean? On Mali lowp and mediump are both fp16, so the suggestion above won't help. Try making everything highp (slower, but will confirm precision issues are the problem).

Comment: Performance recommendations - precompute the gaussian coefficients and store them as a literal array. Split this into separable horizontal and vertical passes. It's 2N samples (N per pass), not N^2 samples, so will be MUCH faster.

Comment: I see you've tried solidpixel's other recommendations, but did you do highp? that's an important check.

Comment: Also lowp float for resolution - lowp float can be approx -2 to +2 - is this intended? You're specifically putting in variables values greater than that (see: [GLSL spec](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf) )

Comment: I have tried highp as well. It did not work.